# Tag name to AMI and its snapshot

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-ami

I am creating a shell script that creates AMI of the specific Instance. I'm using this command to create it and it's working fine.

```
IMAGE=`aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-1234567890abcde --name $(date +%Y-%m-%d) --output text --no-reboot`
```

Also, I want to Tag the name of that AMI and its snapshot which creates automatically. I can Tag that AMI with the below command but not able to find anything to Tag snapshot.

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources $IMAGE --tags Key=Name,Value=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

Even create-image does not have anything related to snapshot

```
       #aws ec2 create-image help
        create-image
      [--block-device-mappings <value>]
      [--description <value>]
      [--dry-run | --no-dry-run]
      --instance-id <value>
      --name <value>
      [--no-reboot | --reboot]
      [--cli-input-json <value>]
      [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

Help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have latest version of cli? See the official docs. It describes tagging image and snapshot. https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/create-image.html

Answer (score 2):

As of Jan 2021, the latest version of [AWS CLI v1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-image.html) (e.g ***aws-cli/1.18.207***) provides a way to apply tags to either AMI or snapshots on creation by utilizing the flag ***--tag-specifications***

[image: Create-Image man page]

For your convenience, I'm attaching my sample shell script:

```
#! /bin/sh


IMAGE=`aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-1234567890abcde --name $(date +%Y-%m-%d)  --region us-east-1 --output text --no-reboot --tag-specifications ResourceType=snapshot,Tags="[{Key=webserver,Value=production}]"`
```

Answer (score -2):

The command creates an Amazon EBS-backed AMI from an Amazon EBS-backed instance that is either running or stopped and tags adds the tags to the Resource type which is image (ami) and snapshot in the following command. You could use your own tags by replacing CustomKey and CustomValue in the following command:

aws ec2 create-image --instance-id your-instance-id --region custom-region --name "name-of-new-ami" --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=image,Tags=[{Key=customKey1,Value=customValue1},{Key=customKey2,Value=customvalue2}]' 'ResourceType=snapshot,Tags=[{Key=customKey1,Value=customValue1},{Key=customKey2,Value=customvalue2}]'

Please refer AWS Documentation for further details:
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/create-image.html

Comment: @Paul I use PowerShell and command does not run with \. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Please provide some description to the command, vs a code only answer

Comment: @Jordash The command creates an Amazon EBS-backed AMI from an Amazon EBS-backed instance that is either running or stopped. AWS Document reference for more details: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/create-image.html